# WP Как вывести значения для первого поста по указаной метке (tag)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как с базы получить значения имени поста, изображения записи и ссылки на данный пост и категории к которому он пренадлежит для определенного тега ?

```
<?php
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'tag_id' => 17 //// Тут id tag-a , посты которого хотим выводить
        );
        $tag = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>

        <div id="home-topBlock" class="home_top">
            <picture class="home_top__pic">
                <img class="home_top__img" width="1170" height="450" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/statics/home_top/MainFront-page.jpg">
            </picture>
            <div class="home_banner">
                <div class="home_banner__category">Home / <a class="home_banner__category_link" href="#">Browsing History</a></div>
                <a class="home_banner__title" href="#">Top 5 Best Keylogger Apps for iPhone and iPad in 2020</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Как получить значения именно для первого поста в данном теге ?

Comment: Когда данные добываются из базы данных, простите за тавтологию, их принято сортировать. По дате добавления ли, по каким-то ещё параметрам. В каком смысле ваша запись (post) будет первой?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что же вам все-таки нужно. Окей, получили вы изображение, заголовок, ссылку и категорию для первого, а что должно быть с остальными? Может измените формулировку, чтобы прояснилась цель того что вы делаете и можно было верно сформулировать ответ.

Comment: Просто нужно получить все указанные данные из поста которому была последнему добавленна данная метка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам ответить на собственный вопрос. Возможно кому-то из новичков в WP (Как мне) это сможет пригодиться

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    //'order' => 'DESK',
    'tag_id' => 17, //// Тут id tag-a , посты которого хотим выводить

);
$tag = new WP_Query($args);

?>

<div id="topBlockFull" class="topBlock">

    <?php
    if($tag->have_posts()) {


           $firstPostId = $tag->post->ID;
           $user_name = get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', ($post->post_author));
           $category = get_the_category($firstPostId, array('fields' => names) );

            foreach($category as $cd) {
                $categoryID = $cd->term_id;
                $catName = $cd->cat_name;
            }

            echo '<picture class="topBlock__pic">
                    '. get_the_post_thumbnail($firstPostId, 'full', array('class' => 'topBlock__img')) . '
                    </picture>
                    <div class="home_banner">
                        <div class="home_banner__category">Home / <a class="home_banner__category_link" href="'. get_category_link($categoryID) .'">' . $catName . '</a></div>
                        <a class="home_banner__title" href="#">' . $tag->post->post_title . '</a>
                        <div class="home_banner__bottom">
                            <span class="home_banner__author">'. $user_name .'</span>
                            <span class="home_banner__data">'. get_the_date('F j, Y', $firstPostId) . '</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
     '; } ?>
</div>
```

Вот ровно так можно получить первый пост из tag ( метки ) и значения к его посту